# passing a variable from R to Tex in knitr

Tags: macros, r, knitr

I am sure this has been asked multiple times since it seems to be a common issue. I looked around but all I could find was the \Sexpr for sweave which does what I want. I am using knitr and I can't find a way to pass the variables from the Rcode chunk to Tex. I want is the variable a to be passed from knitr to TEX as given below. Is this possible? I get the error:

```
 object 'a' not found
```

The sample.Rtex file is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Summary}
\begin{figure}[!h]
%% begin.rcode hist1, echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE, results=FALSE, dev='cairo_pdf', fig.width=8,  fig.align='center', out.width='.9\\textwidth'
% temp_setup_vars(File_1, File_1A, File_2, File_2A)
% generate_graph()
% a = 7
%% end.rcode
\caption{Hist}
\label{fig:hist}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
\par A is \Sexpr{a}. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to respect the fact that you're using `Rtex` format and not `Rnw` format.  See the syntax table in section 1 of [the knitr reference card](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knitr-refcard.pdf) : in particular, you need `rinline{}` rather than `\Sexpr{}`.  I think single rather than double `%` might also help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Summary}
\begin{figure}[!h]
% begin.rcode hist1,results="hide",echo=FALSE
% a <- 7
% end.rcode
\caption{Hist}
\label{fig:hist}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
\par A is \rinline{a}. 


\end{document}
```